# MEAN stack - GET and POST not querying or saving to mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I've having issues with both my routes and getting/saving the data with mongodb. It seems to have validation errors when saving or maybe not posting JSON. Any ideas?

Here's my mongoose schema:

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var sitesEntrySchema = new Schema({
    ip: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    domain: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    wp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    host_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    hosted: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
});

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
var Site = mongoose.model('Site', sitesEntrySchema);
module.exports = Site;
```

And my angular http request

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/mongo')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});

app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.addSite = function() {
        $http.post('/api/create', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log($scope.formData);
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                swal(
                  'Good job!',
                  'Site was added!',
                  'success'
                );
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
});
```

My express routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Site = require('../models/site');

//Return From Mongo
router.get('/api/mongo', function(req, res) {
  Site.find({}, function(err, sites) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err)
    res.send(sites);
  });
  //res.json({"yo": "yo this shit works"});
});

//Add A Site 
router.post('/api/create', function(req, res, next) {
    //create object with form input
    var siteData = {
      ip: req.body.ip, 
      domain: req.body.domain, 
      wp: req.body.wp, 
      host_name: req.body.host_name, 
      hosted: req.body.hosted
    };

    // use schema's 'create' method to insert doc into mongo
    Site.create(siteData, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        //return next(error);
        res.send(error);
      } else {
        return res.json({ message: 'Site added!' });
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without specific outputs that show what is going wrong, here are a few things stick out to me. The first is not always responding with json. You should also try using next() to handle your errors since Express will make sure to send back a correct error response. With these changes, your get route looks like:

```
//Return From Mongo
router.get('/api/mongo', function(req, res, next) {
  Site.find({}, function(err, sites) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      return res.json(sites);
    }
  });

});
```

Secondly, It is best practice to return the newly created resource, so your create route should look like

```
//Add A Site 
router.post('/api/create', function(req, res, next) {
    //create object with form input
    var siteData = {
      ip: req.body.ip, 
      domain: req.body.domain, 
      wp: req.body.wp, 
      host_name: req.body.host_name, 
      hosted: req.body.hosted
    };

    // use schema's 'create' method to insert doc into mongo
    Site.create(siteData, function(error, site) {
      if (error) {
        next(error);
      } else {
        return res.json(site);
      }
    });
});
```

In addition, depending on your version of Angular, you might be using the deprecated promise syntax for the post request. You should be using .then(), not .success() and .error(). This might also be causing an issue.

Lastly, you should try your best to follow REST guidelines for your routes and responses. It will make it much easier to extend your web app and will keep you more organized. Here is a good Express/Node resource for that https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4.

ADDED: Here is an example of how you can log your errors depending on production/development environments

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('err:', err.status, err.message);
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({message: err.messages});
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @peaches! I cleaned up my code to match your suggestions and I' able to create docs now but still can not GET from the db. How can I view the error object when its in next(err)?

Comment: @Calrocks I'm assuming you are running your server in development, probably on localhost? Look at the additions to my answer for how to log the errors nicely. If running locally they should print out wherever the server is being run.